# Make low poly model a bit smoother?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

Hi I am a beginner at Blender and I tried to make this pig model.
I think it looks ok, but I would like to make it a bit smoother (the head mainly).

[image]

Is this possible?

I tried subdividing but that deforms the model a bit too much.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with subdivision :).

One way would be to use the *Subdivision Modifier*
Then just add some loopcuts, to get the shape you want.

*Add the Subdivision Modifier.*

[image]

*Add some loopcuts, to get the shape you want.*

[image]

*And you're done.

That is one weird piglet*

[image]

Comment: Thank you will definitely try this as well :)

Comment: Wow you made a whole model just to answer? respect!

Comment: @MrTheRich I just couldn't miss the chance to make my own ugly piglet :). But you were faster, so have a +1.

Answer (score 1):

you can't make an object smoother without adding more vertices. You can do this automatically with the subdivision modifier, or by hand by adding loop cuts (Ctrl + R) or subdividing certain edges.

There is also a Subdivide Smooth option, that tries to estimate a smoother version. but it doesn't always look great but allows you to manually adjust things afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response :)